# Configure TinyMCE in Typo3 to run over HTTPS

Tags: tinymce, typo3, tinymce-4, typo3-7.6.x

we are using Typo3 7.6.6 for our new homepage. To simplify the process of writing new articles, we introduced the extension TinyMCE4 as TYPO3 RTE. On our test-system tinyMCE works fine, the editors are satisfied.

To prepare for production environment we introduced SSL. Hence the homepage is referenced over https://....

Since this change tinyMCE no longer appeared. After some research we found out, that the tinyMCE extension tries to load a specific dynamically generated js-file *tinymceConfiguration....js* over HTTP (not over SSL as preferred).

[image]

Since we have a strict policy, the server doesn't allow the client to catch the script without using SSL. Unfortunately we cannot change that policy.

The question is: where does the extension get the URL from. Can I overwrite it to reference the https://.. path?

I already tried changing

- config.baseURL
- `tinyMCE.init({
      ...
      document_base_url : "https://.."
  });`

But it didn't work.

Does anybody have an idea?

Regards, 
Thomas

Comment: What is the `<script>` tag you use to load TinyMCE itself?

Comment: I don't explicitely load TinyMCE by inserting a <script> tag. It should be done by the typo3-extension itself. I just need to figure out how I can influence its url settings.

Answer (score 0):

you could try to tell your browser to use "Content-Security-Policy" in that way all http links are rewriten by the browser itself. Maybe the lazy way.

```
https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/security/encrypt-in-transit/why-https?hl=en

http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/security/content-security-policy/
```

Regards
Pete